# Can this if be added to this switch statement?

Tags: c

Hi so I'm building a hotel management program and I'm trying to make my switch statement short but it's not working. I tried to add a function that had the break inside but I get an error saying break not within a loop or a switch statement:

```
void goback()
{
    char y;
    printf("Would you like to go back?(Y/N)");
    scanf("%c",&y);
    if (y=='Y' || y=='y')
    {
        break;
    }
}
int main(){
    do
    {
        printf (" 1. Add a Room\n 2. Current rooms\n 3. Add a booking\n 4. Current bookings \n 5. Modify a booking\n 6. Print bill\n 7. Exit\n\n");
        printf ("Which section would you like to access:");
        scanf ("%d",&w);
        switch (w){
            case 1:
                clrscr();
                newroom();
                goback();
            case 2:
                clrscr();
                roomscan();
                goback();
            case 3:
                clrscr();
                addbooking();
                goback();
            case 4:
                clrscr();
                currentbooking();
                goback();
            case 5:
                clrscr();
                printf("not ready\n");
            case 6:
                clrscr();
                printf("not ready\n");
            case 7:
                clrscr();
                printf("\t\t\t\tLogging out... See you next time!");
                exit (1);
                break;
            default:
                printf("try again");
        }
    }
    while (w!=7);

}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work in C. The error is telling you the truth. Why not have the function return a value (like 1 for yes and 0 for no) that you can test directly inside the switch and break on that? It could be as simple as `if (goback()) break;`

Comment: Wot no `break` statements?

Comment: @lurker That returns error: void value not ignored as it ought to be|

Comment: Not if done correctly. You need to modify the function to return a value. Think through it.

Answer (score 0):

of course, you got an error because of the `break;` statement break you from your `goback()` function and not from `case`.

As you know each `case` block must end with `break;`.

In your case, you must put the `break;` statement at the end of each `case` block and you can make the `goback()` function returning a boolean to decide if you go back or not, but you must define what to do if the user does not want to go back.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but you might want to add breaks after your statements if they are to be executed separately and not in sequence. here I only see your case 7 contains a break, which means all cases until that one will be executed, if that's what you want it's fine, otherwise maybe try something like this

```
switch (w){
case 1:
    clrscr();
    newroom();
    goback();
    break;
case 2:
    clrscr();
    roomscan();
    goback();
    break;
case 3:
    ...
```

Here it seems that your goback() function tries to do that break but what it does it's it tries to break from the context where it if called, here an "if" bloc, which can't have a break inside it. That's what the compiler is saying I guess.